# (Image Processing) Extract texture and fill the empty region

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, texture-mapping

I have an image:
[image: cropped region from image]
 AND I want it to become : 
[image: Filled Region image]
so that the vacant region also filled with the same texture of image. This is the example to show problem. I don,t want to just cut a portion from image and paste it repeatedly on the vacant portion. it will distort the symmetry of image. I want to get this type of result on this image:
[image: Original image]

What are the solution from which I can achieve this solution. Please help if anybody know anything about this problem.

Comment: try quilting or similiar texture synthesis methods

Comment: Also lookup *inpainting*.